# Proof by induction with partial Bell polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, induction, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation in $y_n$, $\forall n >1$: 
\begin{equation} 
y_{n+1} = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n u_k B_{n,k}(y_1, y_2, ..., y_{n-k+1}) 
\quad (1)
\end{equation}
where $B_{n,k}$ are the partial (exponential) Bell polynomials and $y_1 = u_0$.

Somehow I found an explicit form of (1) that reads, $\forall n >1$:
\begin{equation} 
y_{n+1}^* = (n+1)!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{u_0^{n-k+1}}{(n-k+1)!}B_{n,k}(u_1, u_2, ..., u_{n-k+1}) 
\quad (2)
\end{equation}
and $y_1 = u_0$.

I know that (1) and (2) are equivalent (I implemented both expressions in Python, up to order 10), but I can't find a way to prove it.
I have tried a proof by induction, but it leads to composition of bell polynomials... I don't know how to deal with it.

Any idea about how to prove that (1)$=$(2) ?
Thanks in advance,

Tristan

PS: Below you will find the implemented version of (1) and (2) using package Sympy in Python.

```
import sympy as sp
import math

def y_n(n, u):

    '''
    Returns the expression of y_n, according to the following expression
             y_n = n.\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}B_{n-1,k}\big(y_1,y_2,...,y_{n - k})\big) u_k
             y_1 = u_0
    where B_{n-1, k} are the Bell polynomials

    * n: order of y_n
    * u: list of variables (default: u_0 ... u_{n-1})
    '''

    if n == 1:
        return u[0] #u_0 for n = 1

    else:
        poly_lst = [0]*(n - 1) #creates a list to store expressions for each k

    for k in range(1, n):
        poly_lst[k-1] = sp.bell(n-1, k, [y_n(i, u) for i in range(1, n - k + 1)])*u[k]*(n) #calculates the polynomial for each k
    print(poly_lst)

    return sum(poly_lst) # sum over k = 1 --> n-1

def y_n_star(n, u):

    '''
    Returns the expression of y_n_star, according to the following expression
        y_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}B_{n-1,k}\big(u_1,u_2,...,u_{n - k}\big) \frac{u^{n - k} n!}{(n - k)!}
        y_1 = 0

    where B_{n-1, k} are the Bell polynomials

    * n: order of y_n_star
    * u: list of variables (default: u_0 ... u_{n-1})
    '''

    if n == 1:
        return u[0] #u_0 for n = 1

    else:
        poly_lst = [0]*(n - 1) #creates a list to store expressions for each k value

    for k in range(1, n):
        poly_lst[k-1] = sp.bell(n-1, k, u[1:])*u[0]**(n-k)*math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(n-k)) #calculates the polynomial for each k
    print(poly_lst)

    return sum(poly_lst) # sum over k = 1 --> n-1


TEST 
n = 4

u = [sp.symbols('u'+str(i)) for i in range(n)] # List of symbols u_0, u_1 ...
explicit = y_n_star(n, u)
recurence = y_n(n, u)

sub = explicit - recurence
print('n = ' + str(n) + ':   '+str(sub.simplify()))
```